# Jacob's Ladder and Component Identification

Tags: components, high-voltage

What would be the component in the bottom left of the picture?[image: Step 1: the transformer]

Comment: You expect us to watch a video in order to understand your question? That isn't happening.

Comment: @DaveTweed The person who answered my question did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an option for 120/240 primary windings. My guess is it is connected in series for 240Vac operation.

The arc generates ozone, UV and other nasty EMI, not for newbies.

Comment: This looks like the main transformer from a microwave oven. If that's so, those wires are the 4V output for the tube's cathode heating. See https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Mikrowellenger%C3%A4t_Schaltung.png